# pcscd protocol changes but atr does not

Tags: python, smartcard, pcsc, pyscard

I've been working on hid omnikey 5325 cl and trying to get the ATR value. I'm using pcscd and pyscard library on Ubuntu. System automatically gets the ATR using T0 protocol but I need RAW return. On windows using helloprox or omnikey's official software I can get what I need, but on ubuntu even though I've change the protocol but ATR does not change.

here is the code I use:

```
class PrintObserver(CardObserver):

"""A simple card observer that is notified
when cards are inserted/removed from the system and
prints the list of cards
"""

def update(self, observable, actions):
    (addedcards, removedcards) = actions
    for card in addedcards:
       card.connection=card.createConnection()
       card.connection.connect(protocol=CardConnection.RAW_protocol)

    binary_atr=bin(int(toHexString(card.connection.getATR()).replace(" ",""), 16))

       binary_atr=binary_atr[len(binary_atr)-24:len(binary_atr)-1]
       print int(binary_atr,2)

    for card in removedcards:
        print "-Removed: ", toHexString(card.atr)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cardmonitor = CardMonitor()
    cardobserver = PrintObserver()
    cardmonitor.addObserver(cardobserver)

#Get Ports
config=ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read('../config.ini')
Read_Port=int(config.get('CardReaderSocketPorts','Read',0))
Write_Port=int(config.get('CardReaderSocketPorts','Write',0))

# Initialise socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
server_address = ('localhost', Read_Port)
return_address = ('localhost', Write_Port)
sock.bind(server_address)

while 1:
  message, address = sock.recvfrom(4096)
  if message:
    parsed_json=json.loads(message)

    #Single Line
    if parsed_json['set'].upper()=="Stop":
        sock.sendto('{"success":"True"}',return_address)        
        break


# don't forget to remove observer, or the
# monitor will poll forever...
cardmonitor.deleteObserver(cardobserver)
```

Comment: I'm somewhat unsure, what you are trying to achieve. The communication between card and reader will always be T=0, T=1 or T=CL. The chosen protocol depends on the ATR, which typically means, that a card supporting T=0 and T=1 will be addressed using T=0. (I never heard of a card communicating in raw mode.) Stated differently: you have to change the ATR to achieve a different behaviour, which is unfortunately completely dependent on the used card.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, let me clearify my problem. I am trying to achive to change the ATR decoding format. In windows I am using "Omnikey Workbench", allows to change ATR decoding format. In ubuntu the default is H10301.

Also there is an option to use "raw decoding format" which in workbench will be easier for me to work on. 

H10301 ATR: 3B 06 01 00 18 02 87 04 Raw decoding ATR: 3B 05 00 02 24 E0 40I need to get the card number 1208352 which is at the back of the card. It's very easy using the latter one, but I could not figure it out using the first one. Thanks for the reply @guidot

Comment: Actually what I look for is linux version of [this](http://www.isecuretech.com/download/SmartCardReader/OMNIKEY/driver/OK5x21/OK5x25_Prox_ATRDecode.pdf) .Since this code will run on several devices, changing it with a python command if possible. @guidot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting the Omnikey support, the problem is solved.
As in [developer guide](http://www.hidglobal.com/node/5487) I was looking for the config file "/etc/cmrfid.ini" to change the prox format. The file name was changed into "/etc/Omnikey.ini"

Answer (score 0):

Some considerations, which may be helpful, even if they don't add to a full answer:

- You are working with contactless cards or tags
- These tags **have no** ATR, but depending on the protocol something like ATQB or ATS, which is completely differently structured.
- PCSC is a dated software concept, which strictly **requires** an ATR
- So contactless reader manufacturers have to invent an ATR, based on the information they get from the card
- What your software receives as "ATR" is the result of this invention.
- Omnikey apparently uses the Windows registry to control the invention process, which is obviously a non-portable approach.

So my advice would be, to contact the Omnikey support, how to proceed from Linux. According to my experience they are cooperative.